# Wordpress : How to display tags from a specific category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried many solutions, but not good in my case. Do you have an idea to display "best tags" (most use of last 30 days) from a specific category with function get_terms() of Wordpress ?

```
<?php $wpdb->show_errors(); ?>
<?php
global $wpdb;
$term_ids = $wpdb->get_col(
"SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= $wpdb->posts.post_date"
                    );

if(count($term_ids) > 0){
$tags = get_terms(array(
    'orderby' => 'count', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'number' => 8, 
    'include' => $term_ids,
));

foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) { ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link($tag->term_id); ?>" rel="tag" class="text-center">
            <img src="<?php the_field('image', $tag); ?>" class="trend-artist-img">
            <p><?php echo $tag->name ?></p>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php }} ?>
```

With this code, I have the complete list of the "best tags" but not for a specific category.

The category what I need have the ID : 18.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by taxonomy by passing the taxonomy to get_terms:

```
`$tags = get_terms(array( 
        'orderby' => 'count', 
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'number' => 8, 
        'include' => $term_ids,
        'taxonomy' => 'my_category', // e.g 'post_tag'
    ));
```

Or, to filter by a specific category *within* a taxonomy pass the 'name' to get_terms:

```
`$tags = get_terms(array( 
        'orderby' => 'count', 
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'number' => 8, 
        'include' => $term_ids,
        'name' => 'my_category_name', 
    ));
```

These can be combined. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this but it's not working.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does it not filter them, or does it not return anything?

Comment: It is not filter them. If I do a print_r($tags), I have this : `[0] => WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] => 357
            [name] => Caballero
            [slug] => caballero
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 357
            [taxonomy] => post_tag
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 8
            [filter] => raw
        )` for the first object

Comment: But is 'Caballero' one of your most used tags?

If all your tags are in the 'post_tag' category then passing 'taxonomy' => 'post_tag' will narrow the results of get_term to just those tags.

You can also narrow by category name (I've added this to my answer) but this doesn't seem to make much sense as passing 'name' => 'Caballero' would just return the single result for that tag.

Maybe I misunderstand what you're trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

I've re-read your question and I think what you're trying to do is probably not possible with a single query.

The trouble is that both tags and categories are applied to posts rather than to each other, so there's no easy relationship between the two. You could do a new WP_Query for each best tag to check if there are any posts that have both the tag and the category, but that's going to be quite slow and inefficient. Or you could do a WP_Query to get all posts that have that category and ANY of the best tags and then use the results of that query to work out which, if any, of the best tags haven't been used.

Both these options seem more trouble than they're worth to me!

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your reply. I gone try something :)